# 3D secure card validation error on magento 1.7.0.2

Tags: magento-1.7, paypal

We have installed Magento 1.7.0.2 and are using PayPal Payments Pro. When we enable 3D secure we get a popup error:

> This card has failed validation and cannot be used

We have registered on Cardinal and set profile and all things according to documentation. We have all settings in admin payment methods and payment services.

Can anybody help sort out this error?

Comment: Is this on one card only or for all credit cards that you have tried? Have you tried with cards that have 3D secure enabled and with cards that do not have this enabled?

Answer (score 2):

Did you configure Centinel 3D Secure System with PayPal?

On Magento knowledge base:

> 3D Secure Card Validation - Choose whether credit cards will be
>   verified through the Centinel 3D Secure system. The 3D Secure
>   functionality used for credit card verification must first be set up
>   under System > Configuration > SALES > Payment Services > 3D Secure
>   Credit Card Verification. In this case, credit card validation will be
>   performed by the external Centinel® system when the PayPal Website
>   Payments Pro payment method is selected. If the parameter is enabled,
>   the following two fields become available: Severe 3D Secure Card
>   Validation - Choose whether severe validation will be applied to
>   credit cards by the Centinel system. Severe credit card validation
>   removes the charge back liability on merchant.
>
> Centinel Custom Api URL - Enter the URL provided by Centinel which
>   will establish the connection with the Centinel system for credit card
>   validation.